# System.Drawing.Brush from System.Drawing.Color

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing, printdocument, system.drawing.color

I'm developing a WinForm Printing application for our company.

When the document is printed, I need to take the `System.Drawing.Color` property of each Control on the document and create a `System.Drawing.Brush` object to draw it.

Is there a way to convert the `System.Drawing.Color` value to a `System.Drawing.Brush` value?

NOTE: I've tried looking into the `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush()` method, but it does not seem to be helpful.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use the [SolidBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.solidbrush.aspx) class:

```
using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(yourColor)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Jeez! You know how many completely irrelevant posts I looked at that sent me off on wild goose chases? The answer was *so close* but my case was never actually addressed in any of them.

Answer (score 4):

Why not the GDI+ brush?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.solidbrush.solidbrush.aspx

The other one is for WPF.