# How to create a C# brush with transparent color

Tags: c#

I am using C# windows form

this code creates a transparent color named "newColor"

```
            Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red);
```

and here is the code I where I use the Brush

```
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.newColor, mpo.X, mpo.Y, 2, 2);
```

but it's not working, and displays:

> Error 1   'System.Drawing.Brushes' does not contain a definition for
>   'newColor

**how to use a C# brush with a transparent color?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just creating a `Color` object doesn't magically add it to the pre-defined list in `Brushes`.

You need to do this:

```
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(newColor), mpo.X, mpo.Y, 2, 2);
```

To use the color you just created. Credit to [System.Drawing.Brush from System.Drawing.Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734763/system-drawing-brush-from-system-drawing-color) for how to create a brush from a color.